# Delphi project compilation error: Packages 'A' and 'B' both contain unit 'C'

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, package, namespaces, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a Delphi project group consisting of three projects: `Sales`, `Inventory`, and `Orders`.

In the Sales project, there is a unit called `Customers.pas`. The `Inventory` project has a unit called `Products.pas` that imports `Customers` from the `Sales` project. The `Orders` project has both `Sales` and `Inventory` listed in the `requires` clause of the `Orders.dpk` file, and `Customers` is also imported in the `OrdersUnit`.

However, when I try to compile the project, I get the following error:

> [dcc32 Error] Orders.dpk(42): E2199 Packages 'Sales' and 'Inventory' both contain unit 'Customers'

What could be causing this error, and what is the possible solution? I cannot move, delete or rename any files in the codebase.

Answer (score 3):

It is clear from the error that the Sales and Inventory packages are both linking in their own copies of the `Customers` unit, despite your claim that "*The Inventory project ... imports Customers from the Sales project*".

As such, when the Orders project links in both packages, it ends up with 2 separate copies of the `Customers` unit, which is not allowed.

The `Customers` unit MUST be implemented in a *single* package only. Any other projects that want to use that unit *in the same process at runtime* MUST import that unit from that package.

Your Inventory project is clearly not importing the `Customers` unit correctly. For instance, if `Customers.dcu` that is compiled from the Sales project is visible on the search path for the Inventory project, the compiler will use that DCU while compiling the Inventory project, instead of importing the unit from the Sales package. Make sure that is not the case.

Comment: To be honest, I have simplified the scenario to these 3 projects. The actual project group is legacy code base of a twenty something years old product and there are several other projects inside the project group which has the Inventory in their requires list. I am 100% sure that there is no Customers unit in the Inventory project and the only project which contains the Customers.pas is the Sales.

Comment: @Zarik "*there is no Customers unit in the Inventory project*" - in your question, you said: "*The Inventory project has a unit called Products.pas that imports Customers from the Sales project*". Clearly that import is not working correctly. The compiler is pulling in the Customers unit from somewhere else. Just because Sales doesn't contain the PAS file doesn't mean it can't use the DCU file. Try using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which files the compiler is actually touching while compiling.